# Magento - get all options of a custom Widget

Tags: magento

I'm beginig the development of Magento custom widgets, and I have create for my first Widget this  custom options:

```
<text1>
    <label>Text 1</label>
    <visible>1</visible>
    <required>1</required>
    <type>text</type>
</text1>

<text2>
    <label>Text 2</label>
    <visible>1</visible>
    <required>1</required>
    <type>text</type>
</text2>
```

With this function I get My first text value

```
protected function _getText1() {
    $text1 = $this->getData('text1');
    if( trim( $text1 ) != "" ){
        return $text1;
    }
}
```

I want to know how can I get all my options (text fields values) in only one function (with an array for example).

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as array

```
public function getTextValuesOfMyWidget(){
    $textValuesByKey = array();
    foreach($this->getData() as $key => $value){
        $textValuesByKey[$key] = $value->getYourValueField();
    }
    return $textValuesByKey;
}
```

or

```
$this->getData(); // it already returns you all values as an array
```